# Open new page using only cleint side (javascript)

Tags: javascript, client-server

```
window.open('some_addres.php', 'some title','extra parameters');
```

I can use this code or even form to load another page.
Is it possible to use anonymous file instead of existing one (in this case existing file is "some_addres.php") for opening new window/tab? I would like to open new window (or tab) but using only client side so webpage would work even offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use window.OPen() without any parameters. This will open it blank.